# Displaying some markers causing disappearing of the others

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, react-leaflet

I'm trying to write an application showing current location of stops and trams in my city. Every 5 seconds I fetch data from API in componentDidMount() method and pass it as props to my map component. 1st time I display a map every marker is in its place. However, after 5 seconds my stops markers disappear and only trams markers are in place.

I've already tried fetching in different place, mocking instead of fetching tram data. Also it doesn't matter if I use Google Maps or react-leaflet - result is the same.

App.js:

```
class App extends Component {

constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {};
    this.getStops = this.getStops.bind(this);
    this.getTrams = this.getTrams.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.getStops();
    this.getTrams();
    setInterval(() => this.getTrams(), 5000);
}

getStops() {
    fetch('http://localhost:8080/stopInfo/stops')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(stops => this.setState({ stops: stops.stops }));
}

getTrams() {
    fetch('http://localhost:8080/vehicleInfo/vehicles')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(trams => this.setState({ trams: trams.vehicles }));
}

render() {

    function normalizeMarker(obj) {

      if (obj.latitude !== undefined && obj.longitude !== undefined) {
        obj.latitude /= (1000 * 3600);
        obj.longitude /= (1000 * 3600);
      }

      return obj;

    }

    if (this.state.stops === undefined) {
      return ('loading stops...');
    }

    if (this.state.trams === undefined) {
      return ('loading trams...');
    }

    let trams = this.state.trams.map((tram) => normalizeMarker(tram));
    let stops = this.state.stops.map((stop) => normalizeMarker(stop));

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <MapContainer stops={stops} trams={trams}/>
      </div>
    );
}
```

MapContainer.js:

```
export default class MapContainer extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        lat: 50.0613888889,
        lng: 19.9383333333,
        zoom: 13
    };
}

displayStop(stop) {
    return (
        <Marker key={stop.id} position={[stop.latitude, stop.longitude]} icon={stopIcon}>
            <Popup>
                Stop: {stop.name}
            </Popup>
        </Marker>
    );
}

displayTram(tram) {

    if (tram.deleted === true) {
        return;
    }

    return (
        <Marker key={tram.id} position={[tram.latitude, tram.longitude]} icon={tramIcon}>
            <Popup>
                Tram: {tram.name}
            </Popup>
        </Marker>
    );
}

render() {

    const position = [this.state.lat, this.state.lng];

    return (
        <Map center={position} zoom={this.state.zoom}>
            <TileLayer
                attribution='&amp;copy <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
            />
            {this.props.stops.map((stop) => this.displayStop(stop))}
            {this.props.trams.map((tram) => this.displayTram(tram))}
        </Map>
    );
}
```

}

I've spent a lot of time searching for the solution. Would be great, if someone could help me.

Comment: 1st thing is to fix the constructor in the App component. It should be `constructor(props){ super(props); //rest...`

Comment: What is the purpose of this line `setInterval(() => this.getTrams(), 5000);` in your `componentDidMount`? Notice the 5 second?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out - I was calling normalizeMarker() function everytime I render. For trams this would work, because they are coming fresh every 5 seconds, but stops are saved in state once, so for them it was called multiple times messing up coordinates.

Anyways, thanks for your answers! I will look into them so I can improve my code :)